# How to get pass pecentage of tests through Rest API in azure devops

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to extract the pass percentage summary of builds and release deployments through Rest API?
as I would want to compare the results with a threshold and send mails accordingly to the manager for approving to move to next stage deployment.

[image]

Comment: I guess that could work, I accepted the answer, however I will try the approach and post my update soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to leverage the [List action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) of the Test Runs API.

A call to the List action for a certain test run (`runId` parameter in the URL) returns an array of [TestCaseResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#testcaseresult) objects. Its `outcome` property contains the result of a test case. According to the docs:

> Valid values = (Unspecified, None, Passed, Failed, Inconclusive, Timeout, Aborted, Blocked, NotExecuted, Warning, Error, NotApplicable, Paused, InProgress, NotImpacted)

So, you can approach your task in the following way:

1. Run the List action for a test run you're interested in
2. Parse the response and calculate the number of results where `outcome` property equals `Passed`
3. Divide that number to the total number of objects in the response array to find out the percentage

NOTE: if there are a lot of tests in the run, you'll have to repeat point #1 with paging URL parameters (`top` and `skip`) to pull all the results.